# Mixing CROSS JOIN with LEFT JOIN on Redshift

Tags: left-join, amazon-redshift, cross-join

I have two tables: `accounts` and `opportunities`. One account has `0`-`n` opportunities, but only `0` or `1` opportunities at any point of time (within the `contract_from`/`contract_to` range).

I want to report for the past 4 months which account had which opportunity in this month.

I came up with this query:

```
WITH numbers AS (SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4)
    SELECT * FROM
      (
        (SELECT id, name FROM accounts WHERE is_active) AS acc(acct_id, name)
        CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT dateadd(MONTH, -n,
                date_trunc('month', current_date))::date AS start,
                dateadd(DAY, -1, dateadd(MONTH, -n + 1,
                date_trunc('month', current_date)))::date AS stop
         FROM numbers) AS period(start, stop)
      )
      LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT acct_id, subscription_type, contract_from, contract_to
       FROM opportunities) AS opp(acct_id, subscription, start, stop)
      ON (acc.acct_id = opp.acct_id AND
          opp.start <= period.start AND
         (opp.stop ISNULL OR
          opp.stop > period.stop))
```

My problem is, that some of the accounts only have two resulting rows, even thou I did a left join so I expect them to always have four rows with having the months without active opportunity resulting in `null` values in columns `subscription`, `start` and `stop`.

Is mixing these joins not supported in Redshift?

Answer (score 0):

After some more iterations on my query I found out that the left join indeed works, but the order gets mixed up. The rows with the `nulls` end up further down. Probably because Redshift first does the left join and **then** "fills" up the rows which don't have a corresponding right match.

Also: `OUTER JOIN` is the wrong choice here, because if there are more than 1 opportunity at a given date, then the additional opportunity cause more resulting rows.